# Filtering Many to Many relationship where one entity has relationships with all of the other, not just some

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, say dogs and cats, and a third table dogs_cats (with dog_id and cat_id) that handles the many-to-many relationship between them.
What I'd like to do is retrieve a list of dogs, and filter on a provided list of cat ids where the dogs returned have a relationship with all of the cats. I have it working where all dogs are being returned which have at least one relationship with the list of cat ids using `WHERE cat.id = ANY(list_of_cat_ids)` after doing a join

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common type of query, and one way to proceed here is to just aggregate by dog and then assert that each matching dog has a relationship with each cat in the list.  For example, assuming you had a list with three cat names, we could try the following:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.name
FROM dogs d
INNER JOIN dogs_cats dc
    ON d.id = dc.dog_id
INNER JOIN cats c
    ON dc.cat_id = c.id
WHERE
    c.name IN ('Calico', 'Persian', 'Tabby')
GROUP BY
    d.id,
    d.name
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 3;
```